Why can't my Excel VBA execute simple WordDoc.Run "dummy" call?
Excel code:
Sub checkContentStatus()
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

    Set WordApp = New Word.Application
    WordApp.Visible = False ' Set visibility as desired
    
    ' Check if a filepath is stored in Sheet10
    lAutomationSetting = WordApp.AutomationSecurity
    
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Range("macroBook").Value2), ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
    
    'On Error GoTo HandleError
    
    'Change the automation setting to low security
    WordApp.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    Debug.Print "Opening document: " & CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Range("macroBook").Value2)
    
    WordDoc.Run "dummy"
    
    ws_settings.Range("wordVBAenabled") = True
    
    ' Content is enabled, proceed with other actions
    WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    WordApp.AutomationSecurity = lAutomationSetting
    WordApp.Quit
    Exit Sub

HandleError:
    
    If Err.Number = 450 Then ' Error code for disabled content
        ws_settings.Range("wordVBAenabled") = False
        MsgBox "Content is disabled in the Word document."
    Else
        MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
    End If
    
    WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    WordApp.AutomationSecurity = lAutomationSetting
    WordApp.Quit
End Sub

Word code:
Sub dummy()
    MsgBox "Hello world!"
End Sub

Excel fails at WordDoc.Run "dummy" with 438 error: Object doesn't support this property or method.
I feel like I have tried everything. Don't understand why it will not work

I tested the code in Word - it works
I disabled macro security
Basically all security down and still not working
I called it mentioning module and without it
I tried putting the code in the Document
I double-checked the names match


The short answer is that you didn't write it quite right:
Sub checkContentStatus()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim lAutomationSetting As Long

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    
    ' Check if a filepath is stored in Sheet10
    lAutomationSetting = WordApp.AutomationSecurity
    
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("filepathhere", ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
    
    ' Change the automation setting to low security
    WordApp.AutomationSecurity = 1 ' msoAutomationSecurityLow
    Debug.Print "Opening document: " & "filepathhere"
    
   ' Run the macro in the Word documentdummy
   ' Look down
    WordApp.Run "dummy" '<----- HERE
   ' Look up
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Range("wordVBAenabled").Value = True
    
    ' Content is enabled, proceed with other actions
    WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    WordApp.AutomationSecurity = lAutomationSetting
    WordApp.Quit
    Exit Sub

HandleError:
    If Err.Number = 450 Then ' Error code for disabled content
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Range("wordVBAenabled").Value = False
        MsgBox "Content is disabled in the Word document."
    Else
        MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
    End If
    
    WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    WordApp.AutomationSecurity = lAutomationSetting
    WordApp.Quit
End Sub


To run a word macro from Excel, make sure the macro is in the standard module in word. then, use WordApp.run to call the macro, and don't forget to handle any errs and clean up properly.
Sub checkContentStatus()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim lAutomationSetting As Long

    On Error GoTo HandleError
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = False
    lAutomationSetting = WordApp.AutomationSecurity

    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("filepathhere", ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
    WordApp.AutomationSecurity = 1 ' Low security
    WordApp.Run "dummy" ' Call the macro

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Range("wordVBAenabled").Value = True

    WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    WordApp.AutomationSecurity = lAutomationSetting
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

HandleError:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
    If Not WordDoc Is Nothing Then WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    If Not WordApp Is Nothing Then WordApp.AutomationSecurity = lAutomationSetting
    If Not WordApp Is Nothing Then WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
End Sub

This will open a word document, run the "Dummy" macro, and handle the errs if something goes wrong.
